Is below possible in SQL by using view? how?
Current data in employee table



id
empid
sal_type
salary




4
2
var
9000


3
2
fixed
5000


2
1
var
6000


1
1
fixed
10000



I need output as below



empid
Fixed
VAR




1
10000
6000


2
5000
9000



I tried to build select query but did not get output as expected

One easy way is to use conditional aggregation. You could also use PIVOT but I find this a lot simpler from a syntax perspective.
select empid
    , Fixed = max(case when sal_type = 'fixed' then salary end)
    , [var] = max(case when sal_type = 'var' then salary end)
from YourTable
group by empid

